# Yii2 on beforeSend modify statusCode to 200, but browser accept statusCode still is 500

Tags: php, yii2

I control API access by Yii2 RBAC. I want to always return `200` as status code, though `403`. So I added some code to response config in `main.php`:

```
'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
        'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            $response = $event->sender;
            if ($response->statusCode !== 200 && $response->statusCode !== 302) {
                $response->data = Array(
                    'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                    'data' => \Yii::$app->response->statusCode
                );
                \Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 200;                    
                die(json_encode($response));
            }
        },
    ],
```

I set user to not be allowed to access `/test/list`. Then I try to access `/test/list` by this user. I think I should receive HTTP status code `200`, but it is `500` and `response['data']['data]` is `200`. I don't understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `die()`. It will break framework flow and your response will never be sent. If you want to send JSON all you need is to change format of response:

```
'response' => [
    'class' => Response::class,
    'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
        /* @var $response Response */
        $response = $event->sender;
        if ($response->statusCode !== 200 && $response->statusCode !== 302) {
            $response->data = [
                'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                'data' => $response->statusCode
            ];
            $response->statusCode = 200;
            $response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        }
    },
],
```

But be aware that returning status 200 for errors may bring unexpected side effects. For example non-existent pages will be indexed by web spiders as a regular pages, so search results may be full of such error JSONs. 
At current state it will also break permanent redirections (301) , [HTTP caching](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/caching-http) and probably many more, since 200 and 302 are not the only non-error status codes.

Comment: Ok, It is worked. Thank you! I just want to return less data for 4xx and 5xx.